# Applying CSS to first & last TH of a table

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I need to apply styles for the first and last th of the below table using jQuery, wrote some script which is not firing..

```
 <script>$("th:gt(0)").css("border-left", "none");</script>

 <table>
 <tr>
  <th scope="col">one</th>
  <th scope="col">two</th>
  <th scope="col">three</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Any help would be handy.

Comment: Don't forget about the $(document).ready...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`:first-child`](http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) and [`:last-child`](http://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/) pseudo-selectors:

```
$("table tr th:first-child, table tr th:last-child").css("border-left", "none");
```

---

To only apply CSS to the last TH, you can use [`.last()`](http://api.jquery.com/last/), like this (keeping it one line):

```
$("table tr th:first-child, table tr th:last-child").css("border-left", "none").last().css("border-right", "none");
```

Comment: I knew someone more knowledgeable would come along with an example ;-)

Comment: Worked perfectly, i need to add border-right:none to the last TH, how can it be done using the same script

Comment: Now i have written like this   $("table tr th:first-child").css("border-left", "none");
    $("table tr th:last-child").css("border-right", "none");

Comment: Just use two different selectors if you want to set individual properties.

Comment: @Kyle Thanks. You could probably get away with removing the `table` bits and possibly the `tr`, but I wanted to be verbose :-)

Comment: @Interstellar I've edited my question since you posted your comment. Take a look at the second part.

Comment: @JamWaffles chaining is a good thing, but i think separating them out makes it a little cleaner and more explicit. Works either way though!

Comment: But splitting it out actually makes for more code, because you have to re-type the selector. I do agree that it makes it cleaner, though.

Answer (score 0):

I have never tried - but there are pseudo selectors called first-child and last-child. You may be able to target them this way.

However i am not sure on browser support?

Comment: Browser support for these selectors is patchy with IE7, however jQuery's selectors (using Sizzle) are supported cross browser.

Comment: Iam  using this script on IE7, working perfectly without any issues

Answer (score 0):

`$('th:first, th:last').css("border-left", "none");`

That should do the trick.

You can also use:

`:last-of-type`
or
`:last-child`

You can use these in your jQuery selector or just css, and use sizzlejs to provide cross browser.